# Single Line Mysql If Statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to use this code on phpmyadmin but always get an error message:

```
SELECT IF ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                           FROM otthonfenyei_hu_beta_pos.global_products
                          WHERE product_manufacturer = 'Apollo'
                            AND product_art_num = 'SUP-50-GRAY'          ) )
       BEGIN INSERT INTO otthonfenyei_hu_beta_pos.global_products
            (global_product_id, product_barcode, product_art_num, product_name, product_desc, product_manufacturer, product_vtsz, product_unit_type, product_list_price, product_list_price_date)
             VALUES (null, '5905949002762', 'SUP-50-GRAY', 'Hajszárító Linea Piccola', '1200W, összecsukható fogantyú, szűkítő, gumírozott markolat. Túlmelegedés elleni védelem, 2 állású teljesítmény kapcsoló. Szín: Szürke', 'Apollo', '', 'db', '1499', '2011-02-02 00:00:00')
       ELSE BEGIN UPDATE otthonfenyei_hu_beta_pos.global_products
                     SET product_barcode='5905949002762',
                         product_name='Hajszárító Linea Piccola',
                         product_desc='1200W, összecsukható fogantyú, szűkítő, gumírozott markolat. Túlmelegedés elleni védelem, 2 állású teljesítmény kapcsoló. Szín: Szürke',`product_vtsz`='',
                         product_unit_type='db',
                         product_list_price='1499',
                         product_list_price_date='2011-02-02 00:00:00'
                   WHERE product_manufacturer = 'Apollo'
                     AND product_art_num = 'SUP-50-GRAY'
       END;
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ') BEGIN INSERT INTO `otthonfenyei_hu_beta_pos`.`global_products`
(`global_produc' at line 1
```

Comment: you will need delimiters put `;` at the end of each statement

Comment: Are you sure you can have a `BEGIN` out of nowhere just like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use BEGIN just anywhere - it can be used only inside stored programs, check [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/begin-end.html) for more details.

Comment: OK! So how can I check a product about the manufacturer and article number is exists? And if yes update else insert in single line?